# multiple accent Langiage in gather speech in twilio

Tags: twilio, diacritics, speech

As our customer usually talk in different accent, like spanish ,indian and few other english accent. Is it possible to add multiple language accent in gather verb SPEECH RECOGNITION LANGUAGE?

Also I haven't found the "enhance" option in twilio studio.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
 //twiml.say("Testing voice command, please say something");
const gather = twiml.gather({
                    hints:"one, two, help, voicemail",
                    input:"speech",
                    
      partialResultCallback:"https:",
                    action:"https:",
                    language:"en-IN", 
                    language:"en-US",   //,en-US"
                    profanityFilter:true,
                    speechTimeout:15,
                    speechModel:"phone_call",           
                   //"numbers_and_commands",
                   // enhanced:true
                    
                });
        
  gather.say("Testing voice command, please say something and we will 
   transcribe it");             
  callback(null, twiml);
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

The recognized language is a single [value](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#languagetags). You would need to utilize a common way to ask what language they would like to interact with (say in English) before setting their primary language of choice.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#language